# Unable to invoke putty.exe from Teamcity using Nant

Tags: teamcity, nant, ksh, putty

I am trying to build a database release script functionality in the build process through Teamcity. The release scripts are already in a ksh file (they deploy scripts on Sybase IQ server) and hence, i don't want to re-write it.

As such Teamcity is able to run the Nant program and do the build successfully, however, when I added the step to invoke putty.exe from the .build file, it just keeps on running.

Please can someone tell me a way to invoke a ksh script from Teamcity using Nant?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with putty but one of the common things that I find with running scripts from TeamCity is that with certain utilities (git in my case) requires you to accept or confirm something the first time it is run on a machine, in this case the build agent.

The best way to tell if this is the case is to run the script on the machine that the build agent is running on as the user that the build agent service is being run under.

**Note** If you are using windows and are running the service as local system you can use [PSTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) to [run as the local system](http://verbalprocessor.com/2007/12/05/running-a-cmd-prompt-as-local-system/).